# Can't configure unique IPs in Parallels VMs

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, virtual-machines

I have 4 VMs running Ubuntu within Parallels (host machine is OS X). I am trying to set up SSH so that I can SSH into them, but I can't connect to them individually. They are all reporting the same IP with `ip -a`. I've tried it with both the Shared and Bridged networking modes, and get the same thing both times. They all have unique hostnames, but if I try to connect via hostname from OS X, the hostname won't work ("`could not resolve hostname | nodename nor servname provided, or not known`"). If I connect with IP, I can successfully log into the 1st of 4 VMs (confirmed by returning hostname once I'm logged in), but that's the only one I can connect to.

I tried setting up IP port forwarding under Parallels -> Preferences -> Network -> Shared, but when I put the port forwarding rule in for a specific port (e.g., 2200), I can't connect to that port from the host box.

How can I configure the 4 VMs with unique IPs so that I can SSH into them individually? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect with the hostname as found in the etc/hosts file
try ping it first with ping ubuntu20.shared